# Suspend function dosn't resume inside foreach

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

I am using Room Persistence Library inside my Android project.
ViewModel class:

```
class ShoppingListsViewModel(
    private val toBuyProductRepository: ToBuyProductRepository,
    private val shoppingListRepository: ShoppingListRepository,
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {

fun addShoppingListWithProductsToBuy(listName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val listId: Long = shoppingListRepository.insertList(ShoppingList(listName))
            val productsToBuy: List<ToBuyProduct> = toBuyProductRepository.getAllProductsNLD()

            productsToBuy.forEach {
                productRepository.insert(
                    Product(
                        ProductDetails(productName = it.name),
                        listId
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repositories:

```
class ShoppingListRepository(
    private val shoppingListDao: ShoppingListDao
) {

    suspend fun insertList(list: ShoppingList): Long = shoppingListDao.insertList(list)
}
```

```
class ToBuyProductRepository(
    private val toBuyProductDao: ToBuyProductDao
) {

    suspend fun getAllProductsNLD(): List<ToBuyProduct> = toBuyProductDao.getAllProductsNLD()
}
```

```
class ProductRepository(
    private val productDao: ProductDao
) {
    suspend fun insert(product: Product) = productDao.insert(product)
}
```

DAOs:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingListDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertList(list: ShoppingList): Long
}
```

```
@Dao
interface ToBuyProductDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tobuyrecord")
    suspend fun getAllProductsNLD(): List<ToBuyProduct>
}
```

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(product: Product)
}
```

The problem concerns function `addShoppingListWithProductsToBuy`. `toBuyProductRepository.getAllProductsNLD()` always returns valid list. But number of iterations in `productsToBuy.forEach` is random and doesn't depend on size of `productsToBuy`. The coroutine seems to suspend on `productRepository.insert` at some point and never resumes.

Comment: `val l = productsToBuy.map { Product(ProductDetails(productName = it.name), listId) }` replace your current `insert` or add a new function to `ProductRepository` and `ProductDao` which receive `List<Product>` and insert whole list at a time, instead of inserting each item